# API_LEVEL non compliance details ... anything to worry about?

Tags: android-management-api

We recently adopted the Android Management API and we've got around 250 kiosk devices which are in various locations throughout the UK.

I can see a bunch of warnings related to the API level of the device.
i.e `policyCompliant: true`, however there are some `nonComplianceDetails`.

I'm wondering if this is something to worry about? Will the devices factory reset themselves after a certain amount of time?

**An affected device**

```
{
  "name": "enterprises/XXXXXXXX/devices/XXXXXXXX",
  "managementMode": "DEVICE_OWNER",
  "state": "ACTIVE",
  "appliedState": "ACTIVE",
  "policyCompliant": true,
  "nonComplianceDetails": [
    {
      "settingName": "systemErrorDialogsDisabled",
      "nonComplianceReason": "API_LEVEL"
    },
    {
      "settingName": "lockTaskFeatures",
      "nonComplianceReason": "API_LEVEL"
    }
  ],
  "enrollmentTime": "2019-01-25T17:09:08.693Z",
  "lastStatusReportTime": "2019-12-02T11:15:14.869Z",
  "lastPolicySyncTime": "2019-12-02T11:15:10.501Z",
  "appliedPolicyVersion": "4",
  "apiLevel": 24,
  "enrollmentTokenData": "20",
  "disabledReason": {},
  "hardwareInfo": {
    "brand": "XXXX",
    "hardware": "XXXXXX",
    "deviceBasebandVersion": "XXXXXXXX",
    "manufacturer": "XXXX",
    "serialNumber": "XXXXXXXX",
    "model": "XXXXXX"
  },
  "policyName": "enterprises/XXXXXXXX/policies/policy_v41",
  "appliedPolicyName": "enterprises/XXXXXXXX/policies/policy_v41",
  "networkInfo": {
    "imei": "XXXXXXXX",
    "wifiMacAddress": "38:1c:4a:XX:c2:XX",
    "networkOperatorName": "vodafone UK"
  },
  "memoryInfo": {
    "totalRam": "1008689152",
    "totalInternalStorage": "1560133632"
  },
  "userName": "enterprises/XXXXXXXX/users/XXXXXXXX",
  "enrollmentTokenName": "enterprises/XXXXXXXX/enrollmentTokens/XXXXXXXX",
  "securityPosture": {
    "devicePosture": "POTENTIALLY_COMPROMISED",
    "postureDetails": [
      {
        "securityRisk": "COMPROMISED_OS",
        "advice": [
          {
            "defaultMessage": "The user should restore their device to a clean factory ROM."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Corresponding policy**

```
{
  "name": "enterprises/XXXXXXXX/policies/policy_v41",
  "applications": [
    {
      "packageName": "com.example.examplekiosk",
      "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
      "lockTaskAllowed": true,
      "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT",
      "minimumVersionCode": 41
    }
  ],
  "screenCaptureDisabled": true,
  "cameraDisabled": true,
  "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT",
  "persistentPreferredActivities": [
    {
      "receiverActivity": "com.example.examplekiosk/.activities.splash.SplashActivity",
      "actions": [
        "android.intent.action.MAIN"
      ],
      "categories": [
        "android.intent.category.HOME",
        "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "systemUpdate": {
    "type": "AUTOMATIC"
  },
  "addUserDisabled": true,
  "factoryResetDisabled": true,
  "mountPhysicalMediaDisabled": true,
  "modifyAccountsDisabled": true,
  "safeBootDisabled": true,
  "uninstallAppsDisabled": true,
  "statusBarDisabled": true,
  "keyguardDisabled": true,
  "statusReportingSettings": {
    "networkInfoEnabled": true
  },
  "wifiConfigsLockdownEnabled": true,
  "cellBroadcastsConfigDisabled": true,
  "credentialsConfigDisabled": true,
  "tetheringConfigDisabled": true,
  "vpnConfigDisabled": true,
  "createWindowsDisabled": true,
  "networkResetDisabled": true,
  "outgoingBeamDisabled": true,
  "outgoingCallsDisabled": true,
  "removeUserDisabled": true,
  "smsDisabled": true,
  "unmuteMicrophoneDisabled": true,
  "usbFileTransferDisabled": true,
  "ensureVerifyAppsEnabled": true,
  "stayOnPluggedModes": [
    "AC"
  ],
  "setUserIconDisabled": true,
  "setWallpaperDisabled": true,
  "dataRoamingDisabled": true,
  "locationMode": "HIGH_ACCURACY",
  "funDisabled": true,
  "autoTimeRequired": true,
  "appAutoUpdatePolicy": "ALWAYS",
  "encryptionPolicy": "ENABLED_WITHOUT_PASSWORD",
  "playStoreMode": "WHITELIST",
  "policyEnforcementRules": [
    {
      "settingName": "passwordPolicies",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "encryptionPolicy",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "keyguardDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "permittedInputMethods",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "permittedAccessibilityServices",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "applications",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "maximumTimeToLock",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "screenCaptureDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "cameraDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "keyguardDisabledFeatures",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "defaultPermissionPolicy",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "persistentPreferredActivities",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "openNetworkConfiguration",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "systemUpdate",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "accountTypesWithManagementDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "addUserDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "adjustVolumeDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "factoryResetDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "installAppsDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "mountPhysicalMediaDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "modifyAccountsDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "safeBootDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "uninstallAppsDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "statusBarDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "keyguardDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "minimumApiLevel",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "statusReportingSettings",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "bluetoothContactSharingDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "shortSupportMessage",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "longSupportMessage",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "passwordRequirements",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "wifiConfigsLockdownEnabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "bluetoothConfigDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "cellBroadcastsConfigDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "credentialsConfigDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "mobileNetworksConfigDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "tetheringConfigDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "vpnConfigDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "wifiConfigDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "createWindowsDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "networkResetDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "outgoingBeamDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "outgoingCallsDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "removeUserDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "shareLocationDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "smsDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "unmuteMicrophoneDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "usbFileTransferDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "ensureVerifyAppsEnabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "permittedInputMethods",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "stayOnPluggedModes",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "recommendedGlobalProxy",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "setUserIconDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "setWallpaperDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "choosePrivateKeyRules",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "alwaysOnVpnPackage",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "frpAdminEmails",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "deviceOwnerLockScreenInfo",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "dataRoamingDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "locationMode",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "networkEscapeHatchEnabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "bluetoothDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "blockApplicationsEnabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "installUnknownSourcesAllowed",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "debuggingFeaturesAllowed",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "funDisabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "autoTimeRequired",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "permittedAccessibilityServices",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "appAutoUpdatePolicy",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "kioskCustomLauncherEnabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "skipFirstUseHintsEnabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "privateKeySelectionEnabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "encryptionPolicy",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "usbMassStorageEnabled",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "permissionGrants",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "playStoreMode",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "setupActions",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "passwordPolicies",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    },
    {
      "settingName": "policyEnforcementRules",
      "blockAction": {
        "blockAfterDays": 299
      },
      "wipeAction": {
        "wipeAfterDays": 300
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

API_LEVEL errors could be ignored in this case.

Few more suggestions:
1. Try enabling all status reporting policies for your device to have an extended view of the remote device.

2. For the  "policyEnforcementRules" - you could try removing all values actually.
3. This one is probably for overriding overall default, this one is not supported.
   {
     "settingName": "policyEnforcementRules",
     "blockAction": {
       "blockAfterDays": 299
     },
     "wipeAction": {
       "wipeAfterDays": 300
     }
   }

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 

We don't want the device to be factory reset under any circumstances. Since there is no way to state that at a policy level, the next best thing was to take all top level settings and give the most lax `policyEnforcementRules` possible.

But yeah, you are right that's pretty stupid recursive rule. It wasn't intentional, just a copy + paste cry for help.

Comment: I've been contacted via email about this issue to provide more info. To reply to each of your suggestions:
1. The devices are all the same ... we ship these out from here, so most of the reporting available is not really interesting as the devices are kiosks and therefore should be in the same state. I have added softwareInfo which is interesting, as it reports the version of the DPC.
2. I'm a bit scared to remove this TBH as it relaxes the rules. I wish there was a setting that says "under no circumstances wipe this device".
3. This was a stupid addition to the policy. I've removed this 

Answer (score 0):

Updating my policy to the new Google recommended way of managing kiosk devices, i.e:

```
  "applications": [
    {
      "packageName": "com.example.examplekiosk",
      "installType": "KIOSK",
      "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT",
      "minimumVersionCode": 41
    }
  ],
```

Seems to have resolved the issue on the first handful devices that have been given the updated policy. So fingers crossed this completely resolves this issue.

I wish there was a migration guide or something to help when the recommended way to do something changes.